# filter data in datagridview by using two column in one button

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter

how i can filter data in datagridview by using two column in one button
I use this code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = timerTryDataGridView.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = "Station like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
        bs.Filter = "SEARIALNUM like '%" + textBox2.Text + "%'";
        timerTryDataGridView.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

but second filter Cancel first filter
I use C# and access database

any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [`MSDN Documentation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) related to *BindingSource.Filter* Property.

> To form a filter value, specify the name of a column followed by an
>   operator and a value to filter on. The accepted filter syntax depends
>   on the underlying data source. **If the underlying data source is a
>   DataSet, DataTable, or DataView, you can specify Boolean expressions
>   using the syntax documented for the [DataColumn.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) property**.

To apply a filter on DataGridView there is easy way, you could apply row filter:

```
string rowFilter = string.Format("Station LIKE '%{0}%' AND SEARIALNUM LIKE '%{1}%'",
                                  textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
(timerTryDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;
```

Comment: i have this message                                                             syntax error message( Missing operand after 'And' operator.